# Creating a POD wrapper for non-POD types in C++

Tags: c++, memory, casting

At one point in my code I am required to pass some parameters as a POD struct (copy data to CUDA **constant** memory specifically). But I want to pass more "complex" types with user-defined constructors (no virtual methods).

I was wondering if there was any issue (or better solutions) doing something like this to alleviate a POD constraint (basically using a POD struct at least the same size as my object of interest as a proxy for the real thing).

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

// Meant to be used as a pointer to the Derived type.
template <class T>
struct PODWrapper 
{
    uint8_t data_[sizeof(T)];

    const T& operator*()  const { return *reinterpret_cast<const T*>(this); }
    const T* operator->() const { return  reinterpret_cast<const T*>(this); }
};

class NonPOD
{
    protected:

    float x_;

    public:

    NonPOD(float x) : x_(x) {}
    NonPOD(const NonPOD& other) : x_(other.x_) {}

    float  x() const { return x_; }
    float& x()       { return x_; }
};

int main()
{
    // initial value
    NonPOD initial(10.0f);

    //copying to pod wrapper
    PODWrapper<NonPOD> pod;
    std::memcpy(&pod, &initial, sizeof(NonPOD));

    // accessing pod wrapper
    NonPOD nonpod(*pod);
    std::cout << nonpod.x() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The use case is to be able to declare a struct of CUDA **constant** memory with any type (CUDA expects a POD type). Something like this:

```
__constant__ PODWrapper<NonPOD> constantData;
```

I tested this and it seem to work but I am especially concerned about memory issue, namely using memcpy to/from the 'this' pointer of the PODWrapper.

Comment: I think the latest standard removed the concept of "plain old data".

Comment: If you remove the copy constructor, the type will still be copyable *and* it will be trivially copyable (so you can memcpy it). You would have no need for a wrapper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PODWrapper exhibits undefined behaviour in three ways. Here's a fix:

```
template <class T>
struct PODWrapper 
{
    alignas(T) std::byte data_[sizeof(T)];

    const T& operator*()  const { return *std::launder(reinterpret_cast<const T*>(data_)); }
    const T* operator->() const { return  std::launder(reinterpret_cast<const T*>(data_)); }
};
```

Without aligning your byte store you are not guaranteed to have enough memory. Furthermore you must [`std::launder`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/launder) the memory address.

However, the biggest problem is that there is no object of type created anywhere (except for `initial`). The memory is there, but in terms of C++ no `NonPOD` object resides in that memory. You can use [`std::construct_at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/construct_at) and `std::destory_at` to create and destroy the object.

```
std::construct_at(pod.data_, initial);
```

Note that the object is not the same as the memory where the object is stored. Especially for non-trivial types (the concept of POD is somewhat outdated and no longer applicable, btw.). See [TrivialType](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TrivialType) for further information.

*Do not memcopy into `data_`.* It will not create an object and you will still be in [UB-land](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

The access looks fine to me.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. If I understand correctly I have no hope of being able to do what I wanted to do in a quick and easy way. In my specific case, I have to make a memcpy at one point. It is to populate a specific GPU memory (cuda \_\_constant\_\_ memory). The memory is moved by memcpying a C linkage struct. Is there any way to avoid the use of std::launder ? (i.e. in C++14, without C++17 support ?)

Comment: The older C++ memory models work somewhat different in some areas and I have partially evicted most of it from my brain. However, from what I gather you want to do, I'd advise against it. Treating non-trivial / non-pod things as bytes has always been an exercise in extreme care where you can shoot yourself in the foot quite easily and subtly.

Comment: Last question : at the end that I need is a kind of proxy type that is trivially constructible, can be safely memcpyied to from a T* (T is not trivially constructible), and safely accessed through a somewhat generated const T& or const T*. Do do think any safe solution exists ? Thank you for your time.

Comment: @pnarvor It doesn't sound like it is possible. You are likely breaking the *strict aliasing rule* in any of these scenarios. Perhaps you can nail down exactly *what* (not *how*) it is you are trying to accomplish and post another question. Make sure not to run into the [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) -- [What is the XY problem? (and how to avoid it)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you want to make wrapper when it is very simple to convert your "NonPOD" class to "POD" class.

Look at class properties here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/classes

You class lacks only 2 requierements:

- each eligible copy constructor is trivial
- has one or more eligible default constructors such that each is trivial.

To fix that, you need to remove non-trivial copy constructor (you can add default copy constructor if you want) and add default trivial constructor. I.e. this works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

class NonPOD
{
    protected:

    float x_;

    public:

    // Add trivial constructor
    NonPOD() = default;
    NonPOD(float x) : x_(x) {}
    // Remove non-trivial copy constructor
    //NonPOD(const NonPOD& other) : x_(other.x_) {}

    float  x() const { return x_; }
    float& x()       { return x_; }
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << std::is_trivially_copyable<NonPOD>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::is_standard_layout<NonPOD>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::is_trivial<NonPOD>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::is_pod<NonPOD>::value << std::endl;
}
```

Output is:

```
true
true
true
true
```

Comment: The NonPOD in the question type was an example. In my case I wanted to write the representation of a non-trivially constructible object (which I do not define myself) into a special GPU memory which is only writable via a mempcy (CUDA constant memory). At the end what I wanted is to by-pass the constructor (I had chills writing this) by copying the memory of an object directly to a memory location (which is read only after the first write).

Comment: If you want to copy object by memcpy, then you need "trivially copyable" property anyway. And probably CUDA also expects "standard layout" data. So, if you already has these two properties, then adding trivial constructor to class shouldn't be an issue. You don't have to use this constructor, it just must be defined.